# currentFunctionPath property is not working for my stored procedure from Java

Tags: db2, db2-zos

I am calling stored procedure which is created in DB2 for Z/OS from Java.

I want to call the stored procedure without using schema name.

I'm not using schema name for all other SQLs by setting `currentSchema` datasource property.

I came to know that for stored procedure I have to set `currentFunctionPath` property. But this is not working. I'm getting below exception:

```
Caused by: com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.SqlException: DB2 SQL Error: SQLCODE=-805, SQLSTATE=51002, SQLERRMC=DB2T.MYSCHEMA.SYSSTAT.5359534C564C3031;DISTSERV;04, DRIVER=4.24.92
```

Db2 Driver I used: `compile(group: 'com.ibm.db2.jcc', name: 'db2jcc4', version: '4.24.92')`
DB2 version: 12

Anybody knows is it a known issue or I missed something?

Answer (score 0):

Be aware of the difference between **special registers**  (such as current function path ) and jdbc connection/session properties.

In your connection-string you can specify special registers and their value using a specific syntax.

The special register is "CURRENT_PATH" and the syntax is defined [here](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_11.5.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.apdv.java.doc/src/tpc/imjcc_r0052342.html).

Example piece of the connection-string:

...`;specialRegisters=CURRENT_PATH=CURRENT CLIENT_USERID=x,SYSIBM;`

where x is the schema that contains your sproc.

You can set the value of the special registers according to your needs, test it carefully with all of your routine calls especially if you have a multi-schema setup.

You can also set the special registers after connecting to the database, as long as you preserve the syntax, although it limits you to setting one value per special register at a time in this case, unless you use the `DB2DataSource.setSpecialRegisters` interface. Refer to the link above for the details.

Comment: Connection string is created inside a custom framework. It requires changes in this custom library. But we have provision to set datasource properties. That why I'm looking for datasource property way. BTW,  why currentFunctionPath is not working?

Comment: Follow the instructions in the link in the answer.  Special registers are handled separately from regular properties.

Comment: Your link is talking about Drivermanager connection. My question is why currentFunctionPath property is not working for my datasoource https://www.ibm.com/support/producthub/db2/docs/content/SSEPGG_11.5.0/com.ibm.swg.im.dbclient.config.doc/doc/r0054615.html

Comment: Possibly because that property is relevant for Db2-LUW, but not Db2-for-Z/OS special registers.

Comment: currentFunctionPath got worked !!!..It was not setting properly due my custom framework